# How to detect any kepress in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code which detects any keypress when the user is on an input field:

```
// Trigger clicking the submit button if the user ever presses enter
$('.Textinput').on('keypress', function(e) {
    if(e.which == 13){//Enter key pressed
        $('#payment-form').click();
    }
});
```

However, how would I do the same thing if **ever** there is a keypress on a page, regardless of where the cursor/active element is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the listener to the *whole document*:

```js
$(document).on('keypress', function(e) {
  if (e.which == 13) { //Enter key pressed
    console.log('submitting payment form');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>content</div>
<input class=".Textinput">
<div>more content</div>
```

Comment: what's the difference between using `document` and using `'body'`?

Comment: I don't know, actually. I would think that in well-formatted HTML, the `<body>` will always be the only clickable ancestor tag (it shouldn't have siblings), so there might not be a difference.

Answer (score 1):

Use document, In following example it captures keypress event from whole document which reflects to the counter. This solution works for me in chrome.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script
    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    i = 0;
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(document).keypress(function() {
            $("span").text(i += 1);
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    Type anything on page or Enter your name:
    <input type="text">

    <p>
        Keypresses: <span>0</span>
    </p>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use body event

```
$('body').on('keypress', function(e) {
    if(e.which == 13){//Enter key pressed
        $('#payment-form').click();
    }
});
```